# I am trying to do a unit test into the service layer with Mockito, JUnit 5 and Spring Boot but I get NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am trying to do a unit test into the service layer with Mockito, JUnit 5 and Spring Boot but I get NullPointerException.

This is my test class:

```
class UserServiceTest {

@Mock
UserRepository userRepository;

@InjectMocks
IUserService userService;

UserMapper userMapper;

@Test
void when_save_user_it_should_return_user(){
    UserRequest userRequest = UserRequest.builder()
            .email("pedro@gmail.com")
            .password("123456")
            .firstName("Pedro")
            .lastName("Perez")
            .birthDate(LocalDateTime.now())
            .imageUrl("")
            .currency("170")
            .build();
    Mockito.when(userRepository.save(Mockito.any(UserEntity.class))).thenReturn(new UserEntity());
    UserEntity createdUser = userService.createUser(userRequest);


    assertThat(createdUser.getFirstName()).isSameAs(userRequest.getFirstName());
}
```

}

And this is my response:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.jhapdevelopment.moneyhub.usermicroservice.services.implementations.UserServiceTest.when_save_user_it_should_return_user(UserServiceTest.java:41)
```

I don't understand why I get this response, I mean maybe Is it possible that be a problem with dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess mocking does not injecting correctly.

For JUnit 5, you must use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` on top of the class.

Comment: Yes, this is the error but I needed to add another "when" because I had another method into my service.

Answer (score 0):

@InjectMocks
IUserService userService  -> replace with UserServiceImpl